# Use enum in EF model with decimal database field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

my first question here, so I'll try my best.

I am creating a DB model with EF6, code first database with the model like this:

```
public MyModel
{
   [Column("MyDbColumn")]
   public MyEnum MyProp { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
}
```

This is supposed to be working fine, when the database field is set to integer or something like this. But I am working with a provider database to which I do not have access and the field is set to custom datatype, that is inherited from `numeric (3, 0)`, thus I'm getting an error message:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Decimal' type to the 'MyNamespace.MyEnum' type is not valid.

I know I could set up my model like this:

```
public MyModel
{
   [Column("MyDbColumn")]
   private decimal myProp;

   public MyEnum MyProp {
       get => (MyEnum)myProp;
       set => myProp = (decimal)value;
}
```

But the point is that I have a lot of models where they already have enums set up, so I would like a simpler approach, something like: a) change EF mapping from decimal to int, so I could use a native support to use enum or b) declare enum as decimal, which I don't know if it is possible at all.

Comment: Try to annotate the column as `[Column("MyDbColumn", TypeName="numeric (3, 0)")]`

Comment: You saved me a bunch of work, thank you! Just a little note that I needed to set it up only as `[Column("MyDbColumn", TypeName="numeric")]`.